# Can't wait on a fence

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2, transform-feedback

I'm trying to get some data from `TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` with the code below:

```
const transform_feedback = gl.createTransformFeedback();
gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, transform_feedback);
gl.transformFeedbackVaryings(program, ['position'], gl.INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
gl.linkProgram(program);
const feedback_buffer = gl.createBuffer();

const data_length = 2;
const output_data = new Float32Array(data_length);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, feedback_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, output_data, gl.STATIC_READ);
gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, feedback_buffer);

gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.POINTS);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, data_length);
gl.endTransformFeedback();

gl.getBufferSubData(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, output_data);
```

But if I do in this way, I get the following warning msg on `getBufferSubData`:

> performance warning: READ-usage buffer was read back without waiting on a fence. This caused a graphics pipeline stall.

Then, I tried to add the below code just after `gl.endTransformFeedback();`:

```
const fence = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
gl.flush();
wait_for_results = async () => {
    const status = gl.clientWaitSync(fence, 0, 0);
    if (status === gl.CONDITION_SATISFIED || status === gl.ALREADY_SIGNALED) {
        gl.deleteSync(fence);
        gl.getBufferSubData(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, output_data);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

let result_is_ok = false;
while (!result_is_ok) {
    result_is_ok = await wait_for_results();
}
```

The problem I'm having here is that `status` is always returning `gl.TIMEOUT_EXPIRED`. Then I tried to set `gl.MAX_CLIENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_WEBGL` as the `timeout` value in `gl.clientWaitSync`, then I got:

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: clientWaitSync: timeout > MAX_CLIENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_WEBGL

This also happens if I set `gl.MAX_CLIENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_WEBGL - 1`. Next, I tried setting `gl.TIMEOUT_IGNORED` as `timeout` value, with this set, `status` is getting `gl.WAIT_FAILED`.

What am I missing here in order to rid of that performance warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman) for the help in [github](https://github.com/gfxfundamentals/webgl-fundamentals/issues/362).

What I did to get rid of that performance warning with the guidelines in the link above:

```
...
gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.POINTS);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, data_length);
gl.endTransformFeedback();

gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, null);

const fence = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
gl.flush();

let aux_resolve;
const aux_promise = new Promise(resolve => aux_resolve = resolve);
checkSync = () => {
    const status = gl.clientWaitSync(fence, 0, 0);
    switch (status) {
        case gl.TIMEOUT_EXPIRED:
            return setTimeout(checkSync);
        case gl.WAIT_FAILED:
            throw new Error('Something went wrong...');
        default:
            gl.deleteSync(fence);
            gl.getBufferSubData(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, output_data);
            aux_resolve();
    }
}
setTimeout(checkSync);
await aux_promise;

console.log(output_data);
```